# Properties of a sequence of iid rv's

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

[image]

I cannot do part a), and Im fairly sure that b) and c) will follow from it. If possible could I please have a solution to part a) and hints if you feel necessary to parts b) and c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $$n \, 1_{(X_1^2>\epsilon^2n)}\leq {X_1^2\over\epsilon^2} \, 1_{(X_1^2>\epsilon^2n)}.$$ Now integrate both sides, and use 
dominated convergence to conclude  $n\mathbb{P}(|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt{n})\to0.$

---

The sequence of random variables ${X_1^2\over\epsilon^2} \, 1_{(X_1^2>\epsilon^2n)}$
 converges to zero pointwise as $n\to\infty$. Since they are dominated by the integrable random variable $X_1^2$, the dominated convergence theorem guarantees that 
$$\mathbb{E}\left({X_1^2\over\epsilon^2} \, 1_{(X_1^2>\epsilon^2n)}\right)\to0 \mbox{ as } n\to\infty. $$

Comment: How do you integrate the RHS? I get that $\displaystyle n\mathbb{P}(X_1^2 > \epsilon^2 n) \leq \int {X_1^2\over\epsilon^2} \, 1_{(X_1^2>\epsilon^2n)}d\mathbb{P}$

Comment: @1234 Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Yes, but how do you integrate $\displaystyle \int {X_1^2\over\epsilon^2} \, 1_{(X_1^2>\epsilon^2n)}d\mathbb{P}$? Somehow I need to show it goes to $0$

Comment: That's where the *dominated convergence theorem* comes in.

Comment: Yes that is the part I cannot see. There seems to be no suggestion that $X_1^2$ is bounded by some function. I can see that the indicator function is bounded by $1$.

Comment: $X_1^2$ is bounded by itself, and is already integrable. That's what $X_1\in L^2(\mathbb{P})$ means.

Comment: I dont understand how this helps to sandwich the integral to $0$, as $\displaystyle 0 \leq n\mathbb{P}(X_1^2 > \epsilon^2 n) \leq \int {X_1^2\over\epsilon^2} \, 1_{(X_1^2>\epsilon^2n)}d\mathbb{P} \rightarrow 0$. Surely it just proves that $0 \leq n\mathbb{P}(X_1^2 > \epsilon^2 n) \leq \int {X_1^2\over\epsilon^2} \, 1_{(X_1^2>\epsilon^2n)}d\mathbb{P} = C , \text{where C is constant}$. Which does not give that conclusion that $n\mathbb{P}(|X_1|>\epsilon \sqrt{n})\to0.$

Comment: I've added some explanation to my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

For (a): consider $Y$ a simple random variable, that is,a linear combination of characteristic functions of measurable sets. Then 
$$n\mathbb P\{|X_1|\gt \varepsilon\sqrt n\}\leqslant n\mathbb P\{|X_1-Y|\gt \varepsilon\sqrt n\}+n\mathbb P\{|Y|\gt \varepsilon\sqrt n\},$$
hence using Markov's inequality, 
$$n\mathbb P\{|X_1|\gt \varepsilon\sqrt n\}\leqslant\frac 1{\varepsilon^2}\mathbb E[(X_1-Y)^2]+n\mathbb P\{|Y|\gt \varepsilon\sqrt n\}.$$
Since $Y$ is bounded, the second term of the RHS is $0$ for $n$ large enough, hence
$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty}n\mathbb P\{|X_1|\gt \varepsilon\sqrt n\}\leqslant\frac 1{\varepsilon^2}\mathbb E[(X_1-Y)^2].$$